# How to name an item using /give command in MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have put the following command into a command block, but it keeps saying invalid command syntax:

```
give @p spawn_egg 1 17 {display:{Name:"help!}}
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

[image: Command Block Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

You didn't close the quotation marks. You wrote `"help!` instead of `"help!"`.

Apart from that, NBT isn't available on MCPE, so it won't work anyway. But in Java edition, the syntax would be correct with the closed quotation mark.

Answer (score -2):

The command is, `/give @p (item_name) (amount) (data) {display:{Name:"(name)"}}`