# How do I use /give to give named items?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image: Me trying to use the commands I found]

I have tried to find ways to get a named item with give but I can't find a way to get the item. Every time it says Missing ')' and I looked through forums and searched every command and I can't find why it isn't working.

Comment: Does [How to name an item using /give command in MCPE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/315934/how-to-name-an-item-using-give-command-in-mcpe) help? The question it's closed as a duplicate of might as well: [How do I give a player an item with custom properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374643/242480)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give a player an item with custom properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374643/how-do-i-give-a-player-an-item-with-custom-properties) (we prefer to avoid creating duplicate chains here)

Comment: First of all, that's a curly brace. Anyway, you forgot to close the quotes on the string "help", that's why the parser doesn't find the missing "}".

Comment: @pinckerman thats a previous one. I tried "help!"  instead an it didnt work after that a tried other ones and still didnt work